# How to create simpile TCP stream proxy with 0MQ?

Tags: c++, tcp, distributed-computing, zeromq

So we have `N` clients that want to have real TCP connection to a server. We have a server-Gateway TCP proxy we want to implement with [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/intro%3aread-the-manual). And we have `P` real servers in a destributed system that has its own `M` gateways. We to be capable to tall our proxy that it can proxy any of incoming clients to one of our `M` real gateways that are acsessaable only from Gateway  we are creating. How to create such simple TCP proxi server with 0MQ?

I can change code on all `M` gateways... so main Q is: how to create next chain with 0MQ: `TCP Socket => 0MQ socket => 0MQ socket => TCP Socket` so that incoming TCP stream data would be intact on the end?

Comment: language does not really matter - I just want to get what 0MQ API commands shall I use in what order... So please if you know any existant solutions in 0MQ for such problemm post link to tham as an answer.